# How to call index on UICollectionView using IBAction?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, uicollectionview

I am trying to put bunch of options on UICollectionView using IBAction as a trigger to open it each option, but I have difficulty what code should I call to trigger my action using IBAction. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func openNewFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.collectionView.dataSource = indexPath.section == 0
}

func numberOfSections() -> Int { 
    return 2
}

func numberOfItemsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 
    {
        return array.count
    } 
    else if section == 1
    { 
        return 1
    } 
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}


func cellForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?    {
    if indexPath.section == 0 
    {

    } 
    else if indexPath.section == 1 
    {

    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me, Thanks..!!

Comment: Where you added you button in cellForItemAtIndexPath and elaborate it?

Comment: I added it in viewcontroller @DharmbirChoudhary